# Connection pool in tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, connection-pooling

Here is my current config

```
 <Resource
    name="jdbc/data"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TABLE_NAME"
    username="USER_NAME"
    password="PASSWORD" 
    initialSize="10"
    maxActive="50"
    suspectTimeout="120"
    minIdle="10"
    maxIdle="20"
    maxWait="1000"
    testOnBorrow="true"
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
    validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
    validationInterval="40"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="100"
/>
```

This is in global context so multiple apps can use it.
I am little confused about parameters.need some details.
What I understand is

`initalSize` a number of connection created when a pool started.

`maxActive` maximum 50 connections can active at a time.

`minIdle` 10 connections remain Idle when connection is not used else are closed after `maxwait`

`maxIdle` 20 connections can be store as idle.

But When I start tomcat server I can see a 30 IDLE connections which remains forever.Why this happens? Am I missing something ? According to my understanding about connection pool there should only 10 connections should created and can stay in IDLE mode. Is there any specific changes that I have to do with mysql `my.cnf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say...

> This is in global context so multiple apps can use it.

What specifically do you mean?  Is it in *$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml* in the GlobalNamingResources block or in *$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml*?

Defining a *Resource* tag in the *[GlobalNamingResources](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/globalresources.html)* block of *$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml* will cause only one resource to be created across the entire server.  This can then be shared to applications deployed on your system by adding a *[ResourceLink](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Resource_Links)* tag to the *Context* configuration.

Defining a *Resource* in *$CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml* will define the resource once for each application deployed to your Tomcat instance.  Thus if you have three applications deployed, you'll end up with three separate resources.  This is a guess, but probably why you are seeing 30 connections to your database server.

Comment: true guess :-) I define a resource in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml